# VB.NET BindingSource in Module not Updating

Tags: vb.net, data-binding

I have a module in my project that I'm using as a sort of print Queue. I have an error list in it. I want the error list to be bindable so that when you open up the error console, new errors will flow through automagically.

I tried using a `List(Of String)` but you can't bind a DataGrid to a string... So stupid... Anyways, now I'm using a `DataTable` with a `DataView` and `BindingSource`. Problem is, when I first open the Error form, the data is there but new errors don't appear in the form.

I made a very simple test form where I put a timer on it that would generate random numbers and add it to a `DataTable` with a `DataView` and `BindingSource` and it works if all of those members are on the Form, but as soon as any piece of it is in a module, it doesn't auto update, just like my project.

Why won't a `BindingSource` auto-update from a Module?

**Update**

Ok, so in my test project, if I add a `Timer` and a `Label` and on the `Timer`'s `Tick` event set the `Label`'s text to the `BindingSource`'s `Count` property, it shows that item's are being added to `BindingSource`, but the `DataGrid` isn't updating to show the changes. If I minimize and restore the window, it refreshes but won't continue to update. It looks like the `BindingSource`'s `ListChanged` event only fires if the `DataSource` i.e. the underlying `DataTable` is actually on the same form as the `BindingSource`... When I put any piece of it in another Module or Form it won't fire the event. But if I add rows to the underlying `DataTable` from the Form the `BindingSource` is on to the `DataTable` on the other Form, it fires the `ListChanged` event, usually...